# Function is defined, but Error says.. Function is not found ! (Strange)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom-events, greasemonkey

This is my code :

```
function mark()
{
    alert("This is a test box..");
}

setTimeout("mark()",5000);
```

> Error : Function mark() is not found !!

There is some other issue.. as it works on http://jsfiddle.net/russcam/6EXa9/ but its not working in my application.. so can you help me debug this ?

What else can be the reason.. By the way I am running this inside a GreaseMonkey script !

Comment: Is the function defined inside another function, by any chance?

Comment: what environment are you using? Works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/russcam/6EXa9/

Comment: This is not working... for me.. I don't understand why ?
The function is not inside any function, its global !

Comment: It should work.. but its not working !

Comment: By the way.. this is a part of grease monkey script.. if that makes a difference ?

Comment: Is there an element with name or ID `mark`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using GreaseMonkey, any functions you define are sandboxed by GM and not available in the main window.
When you use any of the native functions however, like *setTimeout* or *alert*, they are called in the context of the main window e.g;
when you call *setTimeout* you are actually calling `window.setTimeout()`

Now the function you have defined, *mark* doesn't exist in the main window and what you are asking *setTimeout* to do is evaluate the string 'mark()'. When the timeout fires
`window.eval( 'mark()' )` is called and as discussed, *window.mark* is not defined. So you have a couple of options:

1) Define *mark* on the window object. GM allows you to do this through the *[unsafeWindow](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow)* object like this:

```
unsafeWindow.mark = function(){}
setTimeout( 'mark()', 10 );        //this works but is ugly, it uses eval
```

2) Pass a reference to the local *mark* to *setTimeout*:

```
function mark(){}
setTimeout( mark, 10 );        //this works too but you can't send parameters
```

But what if you need to send parameters?
If you have defined your function on the main window, the eval method will work (but it is ugly - don't do it)

```
unsafeWindow.mark2 = function( param ) {
    alert( param )
}
setTimeout( 'mark2( "hello" )', 10 ); //this alerts hello
```

But this method will work for functions with parameters whether you have defined them on the main window or just in GM
The call is wrapped in an anonymous function and passed into *setTimeout*

```
setTimeout( function() {
    mark2( "hello" )
}, 10 );                              //this alerts hello
```

Answer (score 5):

try to use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qrAvM/)`setTimeout(mark,5000);`

Comment: I shoved in the function in the setTimeout function itself.. and that did the trick for me.. but didn't understood what was going on previously !!

Answer (score 1):

If the only place you need to call the `mark` function from is your timeout try:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    alert("This is a test box..");
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. You can't set timers like this `setTimeout("mark()",5000);` in Greasemonkey.  See [GM pitfalls, Auto-eval Strings](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.231%3a_Auto-eval_Strings).
2. There is currently a bug in Firefox 4. Alerts will fail inside timers. See ["alert + setTimeout = failure"](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1318#issuecomment-975522).  That's why Ander.by's answer does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Grease Monkey part might make a difference. Grease Monkey almost certainly wraps your JavaScript in a function to keep your JavaScript from conflicting with the page's JavaScript.

You're using the string form of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) and there's no guarantee about what context the string will be executed in although it is probably in the global scope. Just because your function is visible where you execute `setTimeout` doesn't mean that your function will be visible when the string is `eval`ed.

So, don't use the string form of `setTimeout` (ever), use Ander.by's approach or Walter Rumsby's anonymous function approach.